Cached TLS Sessions not functioning properly
I am currently using FreeRADIUS with EAP-TLS for client authentication, and I have configured a TLS session cache directory at /var/log/freeradius/tlscache/. However, every time a client reconnects, FreeRADIUS creates new .vps and .asn1 files for each session, even though the session details remain the same, and the previous files are not used as cache.
I've seen this behavior only with Windows devices (Macos, Android, iOS works fine).
A new pair of .vps and .asn1 files is created for every connection, and not used by freeradius properly.
FreeRADIUS should reuse the cached session when a client reconnects instead of creating new cache files.
Logs Showing the Issue:
When a client reconnects, FreeRADIUS logs indicate that it doesn’t find the cached session, even though it previously created one:
For the second connection attempt:
(8) eap_tls: Peer requested cached session: 604b28a21b0839df85aac31a93fc59ae1efa3f58781088cb0df999c05fa9d01b
(8) eap_tls: WARNING: (TLS) TLS - No persisted session file /var/log/freeradius/tlscache/604b28a21b0839df85aac31a93fc59ae1efa3f58781088cb0df999c05fa9d01b.asn1: No such file or directory
(8) eap_tls: (TLS) TLS - Handshake state - Server SSLv3/TLS read client hello

Then it recreates the session file:
(8) eap_tls: Serialising session 1dc61483794f1ea87b11939de76614a292e31d04f0fe045ce1ba9369158ff549, and storing in cache
(8) eap_tls: WARNING: (TLS) TLS - Wrote session 1dc61483794f1ea87b11939de76614a292e31d04f0fe045ce1ba9369158ff549 to /var/log/freeradius/tlscache/1dc61483794f1ea87b11939de76614a292e31d04f0fe045ce1ba9369158ff549.asn1 (1641 bytes)

Sample Cached Session Files:
Here are two examples of the .vps files generated for the same client:
First .vps file:
# SSL cached session
e6c48d5b37efbac1c4c1ec7604cb29a0030f0c6e22c304567c885f61147ea693
        EAP-Type = TLS,
        TLS-Cert-Serial := "6b92ee8fe3454c9b47b46b05a3e74566",
        ...

Second .vps file (after reconnection):
# SSL cached session
e1103d784da8d948197c0346232a22e98863d5d366a75b95f15529622b34f95c
        EAP-Type = TLS,
        TLS-Cert-Serial := "6b92ee8fe3454c9b47b46b05a3e74566",
        ...

As you can see, the session details are identical, but a new cache file is created each time.
Environment:

FreeRADIUS version: 3.2.6
EAP-TLS with TLS 1.2
OS: Debian
TLS cache location: /var/log/freeradius/tlscache/

Why is FreeRADIUS not reusing the cached session and instead creating new cached session files for every connection attempt? Is there a configuration issue or a potential bug that might be causing this?
